# Highcharts SetExtremes Sourcewidth and height

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts column chart(http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/column-chart) with almost morethan 13000 categories on x-axis i.e. i am using datehour axis and i have a bar at specific datehour. Let say i have to take pdf containing all the data, Is it possible? If so can i put extremes max value to 13000.

What is the max value that Highcharts support in case of SetExtremes, Source width and SourceHeight?

I can not fine these values on Highcharts website.

Thanks.

Comment: setExtremes isn't limited in any way, only by JS max number. If phantomJS doesn't have limits for height/width in exporting to PDF, then neither Highcharts library has.

Comment: If setExtremes has no limit then i am using this statement in my code window[theSelectedChart].xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, categoriesLength - 1); where the categories are 13000. I am getting this error on console http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Yes, just read carefully that error :) The best solution for your case is to set different `tickInterval` (since `tickPixelInterval` doesn't work with categorized axis). Or just replace categories with linear axis. But still, that won't display all categories. I would rather first resize chart size, then call set extremes.

Comment: How would you resize the chart before calling setExtremes, Can you point me to any related fiddle...

Comment: Somewhere you are calling setExtremes() right? Just line before call `chart.setSize(new_width, new_height);` Still I'm concerned about your requirement. You want to display 13000 bars in pdf file. what is the maximum width (in pixels) for such PDF? I'm pretty sure it's less than 13000px.. (and it's just setting 1px per column!).

Comment: You are almost near to understand my problem. I am not having 13000 bars but instead i have nearly 13000 categories on xaxis. let say categories means from 2012-01-01 00H and 2012-01-01 01H and so on till 2014-12-30 23H,which makes nearly 13000 categories with a horizontal scroll bar on below the chart.Now, i have columns at particular hours in some year(Assume one column at 2013-12-01 03H and one more at 2013-12-04-02H)and i want to download the whole chart in single pdf file which currently not supporting. Does highcharts supports more than one page pdf downloads to accommodate all the data?

Comment: First of all, I'm curious why you are using categories for dates? Wouldn't be better to use datetime axis? Anyway, I tried to export 1300 (only!) which works okay: http://jsfiddle.net/9459stu9/ - however, I'm not sure if that's the PDF file you want to achieve.. When using 13000 of points there is error with exceeded maximum size of SVG file to be exported, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. In the given fiddle you have categories displayed or adjusted so that they fit in several rows on x-axis. That might be fine in your perspective. I have specific data at specific hour(i mean a column at particular hour) in a year. I must distinguish that form other hour that is because the data is only generated in that hour and belongs to it. A similar fiddle was here http://jsfiddle.net/P45Hy/3/ and in that only month and year was available and in my case i have 2012-01-01 00H and so on till the user selected range.

Comment: You can simply change width in my example to .. 500 000px (I love it!): http://jsfiddle.net/9459stu9/1/ - now labels won't be in multiple lines...

Comment: I tried to display the axis in year-month-day-hour format but some how not got correctly. You might understand my problem a bit clearer. Updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/P45Hy/144/. OH! Sorry did not see your message in middle.

Comment: You are exactly right with your fiddle what i am trying to do here.  Now the question comes here, Can i download this chart as PDF?

Comment: "When using 13000 of points there is error with exceeded maximum size of SVG file to be exported, sorry"----> I mean here, what is the maximum size supported here?No doc's available at highcharts website. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: Can i down load it to many pages PDF with chart shared in different pages. This Problem applies to Bar type charts when there is more data like this http://jsfiddle.net/7racxxu0/14/. Can we have also several pages PDF with chart shared in different pages in this case too!

Comment: I suggest to contact us directly on our [mail support](http://www.highcharts.com/support), so we will pass on your question to the team responsible for exporting server.